# how do i view a "view" i created in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, view

So, general question for you smart folks…I created a view in MySQL for an assignment im working on and MySQL stated that it was successful. My question is, how do I view the "view" I created to see if it worked and gives me the right info?

ps Im super new to SQL so forgive my ignorance on these topics.

Comment: `select * from your_view_name`?

Comment: I knew it would be something super simple!